# scratchbox v/s Qemu

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, qemu, scratchbox

I was going through the following link :--
http://jecxjo.motd.org/code/blosxom.cgi/devel/cross_compiler_environment

Here scratchbox is called as an Jail while QEmu is called as an emulator.

> our jail (Scratchbox2) and our emulator (QEmu)

As what i know Scratchbox create an enviroment for compiling then what will QEmu will do ?

What is the exact role played by Qemu & Scratchbox in cross-compilation.

confused .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QEmu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) basically provides(emulates) the central processing binaries through dynamic binary translation and provides a set of device models, enabling it to run a variety of unmodified guest operating systems. Means if you are going to build some kernel or driver for any type of hardware(which is in the list of QEmu) without having the hardware you can build your task.

[Scratchbox2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchbox2) is cross-compilation toolkit designed to make embedded Linux application development easier. It also provides a full set of tools to integrate and cross-compile an entire Linux distribution. It is also having the QEmu and other tools required to build a particular kernel or driver for the hardware.